# Deployment hangs on Java EE project in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Here is where it hangs:

"Initial deploying test1 to C:\Users\Derek\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test1\dist\gfdeploy\test1
Completed initial distribution of test1"

I did a build and the directory above has been created and I have checked my deploy applications page on Glassfish to see if it is there and it isn't.  Tried several times and have waited more than 20 minutes.

This same question was asked back in 2013 but there wasn't a response so i had no choice but to ask it again.

Comment: How is your project composed? Maybe the app is waiting (eternally) for some resource to become available. But we can only guess unless you provide more details of your specific problem.

Comment: It is on an EE module, is that what you mean by composed?  I am also using a WAR and EJB file.

Comment: So it ended up timing out and the server log kept repeating this error:
"Caused by: com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.PoolingException: Connection could not be allocated because: The connection was refused because the database sample was not found."

Comment: I think the issue that I need to somehow get the deployment to recognize my DB file "test1" which is connected, and not try to find db file "sample".  Using NetBeans and trying to figure out how to do this.